# django-allauth + django-invitations: IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/, duplicate username

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-invitations

I am using django-allauth + django-invitations. When I access the url in the emailed invitation sent from django-invitations, I receive this error.

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_userplus_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_userplus_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
```

UserPlus is my custom model name

Answer (score 0):

I had `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None` in my `settings.py` file. Removing this resolves the error - an empty username (I think)